# Adding error bars correctly to a stack bar graph in R

Tags: r, errorbar, stacked-bar-chart

```
ggplot(data=BTNOAG, aes(x=ele, y=Biomass, group = LiveDead)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=LiveDead), position='stack', stat="identity", width=0.75) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Biomass-STE, ymax=Biomass+STE), position = position_dodge(.05),width = 0.2) +
theme_bw(base_size=16)
```

The error bars are not placed correctly when I run the code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkfWL.png)

## Tried Reshaping the data from wide to long format but didnt come out stacked anymore

```
BTNOAG_long <- BTNOAG %>%
pivot_longer(cols = c(Live,Dead), names_to = "Status", values_to = "Value")

ggplot(data = BTNOAG_long, aes(x = ele, y = Value, fill = Status)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.75) +
geom_errorbar(
aes(ymin = Value - STEL, ymax = Value + STEL),
position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
width = 0.2
) +
facet_wrap(~Species) +
labs(title = "Biomass by ele",
x = "ele",
y = "Biomass",
fill = "Status") +
theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(BTNOAG)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(BTNOAG, 20))`.

Comment: Also, your first code does not match the data image, there is no column `LiveDead`.

Comment: Error bars on stacked bar plots are difficult to interpret, ambiguous, and are a poor choice for visualization in general. Have you considered alternatives?